# How can I get rid of text I have put on my lockscreen?

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-tab

I have a Galaxy Tab 10.1 version 1 and i put some text on the lockscreen and have sync updated my device and I can't undo this text. Is there a solution without resetting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the **Settings** app. Choose **Security**, then **Owner info**. Uncheck **Show owner info on lock screen**.